# Will this one tile water suffice the need of fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I just embarked on a map with 2 naturally spawned ponds, each 1x1.
There is no other source of water. (With use of dfhack with a cheat I found that there was no water.) So I decided to create an artificial pond in the meeting area and fill it. It's done - I used a pump to clear the water. But, **will this one tile of water [5/7] suffice my fortress needs ?**

[image: Ponds]

The pond a got dried out in an attempt to increase its size for rain water harvesting.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, depending on how much rainfall you get.

Dwarves don't need to drink water and can survive solely on alcohol. They will usually only drink water in emergencies, i.e. running out of booze or if they are badly injured.

Using a well (dwarves prefer this to drinking directly from a pool or pond) uses 1 level of water per 10 uses, so that 5/7 pool will provide 50 buckets of water. This should be more than enough unless a lot of dwarves get badly injured or you run out of alcohol.

Remember to refill the indoor pool whenever you can. The outdoor pools will refill naturally when it rains.

Comment: when i want to refill the water i need to put water in a channel shown on left side of pump. instead of getting water from outside ,pond filling dwarves fill channel taking water from the water in meeting hall. this is not what i want     

![image](http://i.imgur.com/TVo2XIe.png) 

 *any other method to refill the pond ?*

Comment: "Dwarves don't need to drink water and can survive solely on alcohol." Just like my mother.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, wall off the pool.  You don't want it evaporating from spread.
Second, use that pump instead of buckets.  Just wait for it to build up to like 3/7 or something, then pump.